# How can I save my DirectX choice in Saints Row: the Third so it stops asking me about it?

Tags: pc, saints-row-the-third

Whenever I start up Saints Row the Third from Steam, it asks me whether I want to wimp out and use DirectX 9 or be all hardcore and stuff with DirectX 10/11. Of course, I always pick the latter, but getting asked every single time I run the game is kinda irritating. It's not like my answer is going to change.

Is there any way to always pick one of those options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the launcher with your chosen game executable. A summary of the steps [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?s=31837888c6bacbf843e9b6da8966f0fe&p=31682100&postcount=3):

1. Copy the Saints Row `.exe` files in your Saints Row the Third install directory to a different folder (that should be `game_launcher.exe`, `saintsrowthethird.exe`, and `saintsrowthethird_dx11.exe`)
2. Copy back the one you want to always use - `saintsrowthethird_dx11.exe` to use the DirectX 11 version, or `saintsrowthethird.exe` to use the non-DirectX 11 version.
3. Rename the file you copied to `game_launcher.exe`.

This tricks Steam into directly running the version of the game you want, instead of putting you through the launcher.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the folder in which SR3 is installed their is a exe for each DirectX version if you run that exe it will load the game. Just simply set up a shortcut for that exe.

Comment: Sounds promising, but I'm using Steam - I'll see if this method works with it when I get home.

Comment: It should work, however I had the stand alone version

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to work on the Steam version - there's saintsrowthethird.exe and saintsrowthethird_dx11.exe in there, but running either of them gives me the "pick one" prompt.

Comment: Sorry about that.